# How to use an ApplicationContext as the startup object in visual studio (without application framework)?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have created a "Empty Project(.NET Framework) Visual Basic"
[image: Empty Project(.NET Framework) Visual Basic]

I then added an empty Class object
[image: empty Class object]

Next I added the reference to System.Windows.Forms
[image]

And put the following code in the Class to make it an ApplicationContext

```
Imports System.Windows.forms
Public Class Class1
    Inherits ApplicationContext
End Class
```

Lastly I tried setting the Startup Object to my Class1

However that is not an option ?

[image: Startup object choices]

I tried adding a Sub Main to my Class1
but this had no effect

```
Imports System.Windows.forms
Public Class Class1
    Inherits ApplicationContext
    Sub main()
    End Sub
End Class
```

At this point, hitting start fails with this error
Error   BC30737 No accessible 'Main' method with an appropriate signature was found in 'Project4'.
[image: https://i.imgur.com/AHjU7lX.png]

At this point I could add a module with the following code
and that would compile without errors and run
    Module Module1
        Sub main()
        End Sub
    End Module

But that runs for an instant and terminates

In another similar program I have made, I know I could put the following code in a module instead

```
Module Module1
    Public myClass1 As Class1
    Sub main()
        myClass1 = New Class1
        Application.Run(myClass1)
    End Sub
End Module
```

And that would run until I called Application.Exit()

However in this specific case, the Application Framework is disabled so this solution does not work.

So another solution I have found is to use Sleep(50) in a while loop

```
Imports System.Threading
Module Module1
    Public myClass1 As Class1
    Sub main()
        While True : Thread.Sleep(50) : End While
    End Sub
End Module
```

While I cannot find anything explicitly wrong with this, it strikes me as very inelegant.

It doesn't consume noticeable cpu time or memory
[image]

I just wonder if there isn't an equivalent way to do that using just ApplicationContext and dispose of the module entirely ?

If you have any suggestion I would love to hear them at this point.
I wrote this hoping to find a solution as I write the question but I am stuck at this point.

Where does the code go after Application.Run(myClass1)
It's probably looping something inoffensive while waiting for something to happen but what ?

thanks

Comment: Here's an example I created some years ago that you may find useful:  http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?636812-Formless-Tray-Application

Comment: I posted that previous comment without having read your post carefully, so it may or may not be of assistance. `Application.Run` creates a message pump, so you might want to do some more reading on that.

Comment: Thanks, my current scheme is very similar to this. I started from this project example https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/75822/Create-a-System-Tray-Application-in-VB-NET. The issue is that I have the application framework disabled because I compile manually from VBC.exe and it makes it more difficult.

Comment: Why is it that I can have a single class that inherit system.windows.forms and that can be a valid Startup Object but the Appcontext class is not ?

Comment: Because that's how it was designed. Remember that one of the aims of VB.NET is to be easy to use for beginners. The overwhelming majority of WinForms apps will have a form as the startup object and virtually all of those created by beginners so making that so easy that they don't even have to think about it makes sense. If you're creating your own derived `ApplicationContext` then you know a bit more than the average beginner so writing your own `Main` method shouldn't be an issue. I'm not quite sure why you're against doing so. Every C# project has a visible `Main` method and noone complains.

Comment: Do I need more than
While True : Thread.Sleep(50) : End While
In Sub Main to keep it going ?
Could I put less in there ?
What is in the Sub Main of a Form Class ?

Comment: There is no `Main` method in a form class unless you put one there. If you disable the Application Framework and use a form as the startup object, a `Main` method will simply be generated that calls `Application.Run` and passes an instance of that form. I'm not really sure what the problem is. Why can you not simply write your own `Main` method that calls `Application.Run` and passes an instance of your derived `ApplicationContext`, then select `Sub Main` as the Startup Object for the project? That's what I did in my example and it worked fine.

Comment: I wonder whether the issue here is the project type.  When I created my demo, I created a Windows Forms Application project.  If you didn't do that then you may be missing certain required infrastructure.  Depending on your IDE version, you may be able to change that in the project properties or you may have to create a new project.

Comment: First, thanks for your help
I started from an empty project (because I want the most minimalist project possible, I need to compile using VBC.exe on computers without visual studio)
The application framework is disabled in this case (which is good, it makes compiling easier)
However application.run() is not available
I have declared Shared Sub Main() in my Class1 and put while true sleep(50) loop in there. That runs indefinitely. I'm not sure what is the difference between that and using application.run.

Comment: Here is the latest version of my barebone project
A single Class1 class, containing a shared sub main
Application framework is still disabled
This will run until the Class1.TimeToShutdown = true
I have added a tray icon for control
This compiles and run without error. The tray icon appears
However, when I click the tray icon, nothing happens. The events don't fire.
I guess this is because I'm not using the Application.Run (which is unavailable)
Do I have an alternative left to enabling the application framework ?

Comment: Here is the code for this latest version 
https://pastebin.com/qs7w7K4W

Comment: `Application` is the `System.Windows.Forms.Application` class so it is "available" if you have referenced `System.Windows.Forms.dll`.

Comment: You are right !  This works as expected https://pastebin.com/w1Yjm7A7
Single class file, no module, no application framework, I think that's that's the simplest expression possible of that barebone app. 
Thanks !

Comment: If you don't mind I will post the latest code version and instructions as an answer

Comment: It's not really about whether I mind or not but that's exactly what you should do anyway.

Comment: Ok, I did, it mostly works, except for one thing which is outside the scope of the question but was part of my motivation to post this.  Manual building of the solution using vbc.exe .  It actually works but I added a resource to the second version of the solution and it seems something is wrong. Anyway, it mostly works and it does answer the question so I'm leaving it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to make the barest bone (console or non-console) application using the ApplicationContext Class.

In Visual Studio create a "Empty Project(.NET Framework) Visual Basic" 
[image: "Empty Project(.NET Framework) Visual Basic"]

then add an empty class

[image: add empty class]

Add the following reference by right-clicking on Reference in the Solution Explorer
[image: Add reference]

System.Windows.Forms
[image: System.Windows.Forms]

Now paste the following code in your class

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Public Class Class1
    Inherits ApplicationContext
    Shared Sub Main()
        Dim myClass1 As Class1
        myClass1 = New Class1
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(myClass1)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now hit start and you've got a perfectly working useless application that does nothing with least amount of stuff that I could manage.

If you are here, I suspect that you also would like to manually compile this project from anywhere without having visual studio installed.

Very easy ! In your project folder, create a text file and rename it compile.bat

[image: Project files]

Paste this code in compile.bat

```
path=%path%;c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319
VBC /OUT:bin\Debug\app.exe /imports:System.Windows.Forms /T:winexe *.vb
pause
```

#### **BONUS ROUND**

This app does nothing, how do you know the events even work ?

Let's add, a tray icon, a resource file to add the tray icon and some events

First add a new reference to system.drawing

[image: Add reference]
[image: system.drawing reference]

Go to project properties

[image: Project properties]

Create a new resource file

[image: Create resource file]

Add some random *.ico file

[image: adding icon]

Now replace the following code in the class

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Public Class Class1
    Inherits ApplicationContext
    Shared Sub Main()
        Dim myClass1 As Class1
        myClass1 = New Class1
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(myClass1)
    End Sub

    Private WithEvents Tray As NotifyIcon

    Public Sub New()
        Tray = New NotifyIcon
        Tray.Icon = My.Resources.appico
        Tray.Text = "Formless tray application"
        Tray.Visible = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub AppContext_ThreadExit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles Me.ThreadExit
        'Guarantees that the icon will not linger.
        Tray.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Tray_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles Tray.Click
        Console.WriteLine("Tray_Click")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Tray_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles Tray.DoubleClick
        Console.WriteLine("Tray_DoubleClick")
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit()
    End Sub
End Class
```

And now, to compile this manually

First, find [resgen.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/resgen-exe-resource-file-generator) somewhere on your harddrive
and copy it in your "My Project" folder, you can probably download it from somewhere
[image: copying resgen.exe]

Make sure you've got version 4 or above of resgen though
[image]

And overwrite the compile.bat with this new code

```
path=%path%;c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319
cd "My Project"
resgen /usesourcepath "Resources.resx" "..\bin\debug\Resources.resources"
cd ..
VBC /OUT:bin\Debug\app.exe /resource:"bin\debug\Resources.resources" /imports:System.Drawing,System.Windows.Forms /T:winexe *.vb "My Project\*.vb" 
pause
```

Unfortunately, this last compile.bat doesn't work for me, it might work for you.
Mine compiles just fine, but the app crashes on start.

This worked in another project where I made the Resource files by hand but something is wrong with

I tried adding the root namespace to the build with /rootnamespace:Project5 but this had no effect

Still good enough for now, this last bit will be edited if a fix is ever found